# Asynchronous non-blocking HTTP requests in C

Tags: c, multithreading, design-patterns, curl, libcurl

I would like to make a unix process (client) in C to make asynchronous non-blocking HTTP requests to an HTTP server.

Is there any recommended design pattern that I can follow? I am thinking two threads Sender/Receiver and using libcurl (multi). Is there any example that combines threads and curl multi?

I have seen the example in the http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multi-post.html but I cannot understand how I can distinguish which response corresponds to which request.

Comment: Given that your program will essentially be sleeping for most of its time, it seems over the top to make this multithreaded. Simple asynchronous I/O in a single thread should be all that's needed.

Comment: The process will be triggered by other processes in order to make any HTTP requests to the server, so I do not expect to be sleeping (busy a lot) most of the time.